# jinja2 and weasyprint path to image

Tags: python, jinja2, weasyprint

My code convert the jinja2 template into PDF using weasyprint.
Everything work fine except I can't get the image to appear in the PDF.

My files structure:

```
dist
src
    img
        image.png
    templates
        statement.html.j2
build.py
```

"build.py"

```
import jinja2
import json
import os
import weasyprint
from weasyprint.fonts import FontConfiguration


def main():
    if not os.path.exists('dist'):
        os.makedirs('dist')
    jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
            loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('src/templates')
        )
    css_dir = 'src/css'
    html_tpl = jinja_env.get_template('statement.html.j2')
    with open('sample/json/statement.json', 'r') as f:
        statement = json.load(f)
    statement = statement['statement']
    font_config = FontConfiguration()
    html = html_tpl.render(statement=statement)
    css_files = [weasyprint.CSS(os.path.join(css_dir, filename))
        for filename in os.listdir(css_dir)]
    rendered_html = weasyprint.HTML(
        string=html
    )
    rendered_html.write_pdf(
        'dist/statement.pdf',
        stylesheets=css_files,
        font_config=font_config
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

"statement.html.j2"

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="../img/image.png">
```

Is the image path correct? 
How I can reference the image in the template?
What will be the path then?
Or the issue is not related to the image reference?

Comment: It looks like you have the relative path correct given what you've said your directory structure is, but just for troubleshooting, do you have problems still if you replace `../img/image.png` with the full path to the image?

Comment: @HFBrowning It wok if I give absolute path.

Comment: So therein lies your problem. Just fix your relative path and you should be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered here :
[Image ignored in PDF rendering with jinja2 and weasyprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211774/image-ignored-in-pdf-rendering-with-jinja2-and-weasyprint),

you need to add `base_url='.'` here :

```
HTML(string=html_out, base_url='.').write_pdf(outfile)
```