# Image ignored in PDF rendering with jinja2 and weasyprint

Tags: python, image, pdf, jinja2, weasyprint

I am running an analysis script in python that gives me some variables and an image that I save as a `png` file. I then use `jinja2` to fill them into an `html` template and I use `weasyprint` to render the html into a PDF file that I save.

There are a number of questions on here that deal with this issue, but none of the suggested solutions have fixed my problem. I need to feed it the **absolute** path to the image, since the output data gets saved on a totally different part of my local disk than the code that generates it. Many of the offered solutions suggest to use something like `request.base_url()`, but that seems something to come from `flask` (I guess?) or something that is actually building an app as opposed to simply building a PDF file.

The function that generates the PDF file from the variables looks like this:

```py
def create_pdf_report(varlist, outfile):

    # Create Jinja environment and get template
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('<absolute-path-to-dir-with-template>'))
    template = env.get_template('report_template.html')

    # Render HTML with input variables
    html_out = template.render(varlist)

    # Generate PDF
    from weasyprint import HTML
    HTML(string=html_out).write_pdf(outfile)
```

The template is this:

```html
<img src="{{ systematics_figure }}" alt="systematics" width="900" height="650">
```

And the `varlist` dictionary I pass in looks like this:

```py
fig3_fname = '<absolute-path-to-image>'
varlist = {'systematics_figure': fig3_fname}
```

While plain variables that I give it render fine, the image is not displayed; I get its `alt` text instead. The process finishes fine but I can't get the `png` image to be displayed. When I stick in the absolute image path into the html file directly and open it in my browser, it appears fine.

What can I do to make this work?

I am on a macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and working in python 3.7.3.

Answer (score 10):

Turns out the solution was to add `base_url='.'` in `weasyprint.HTML()`:

```py
HTML(string=html_out, base_url='.').write_pdf(outfile)
```

and to use `png` files instead of `pdf` figures.

Comment: My friend! You are a savior! Thank you so much! I wish I could upvote twice :-)

Comment: Indeed! Spent days on this. There is no way I'd have figured this without this answer. Thank you!